# Можно ли сделать выборочную подписку на рассылку в WP?

Tags: wordpress

Доброе утро!
Подскажите пожалуйста, вероятно у кого-то есть плагин на примете по рассылке, но прежде чем подписаться я бы хотел сделать вывод всевозможных рубрик для подписки, те выбрал чекбоксы и получаем рассылку только на те рубрики которые были выбраны с лк.
Приблизительно это долно выглядеть вот так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> плагин на примете по рассылке, но прежде чем подписаться я бы хотел сделать вывод всевозможных рубрик для подписки, те выбрал чекбоксы и получаем рассылку только на те рубрики которые были выбраны с лк.

Я это когда-то делал с пом плагина [subscribe to category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/subscribe-to-category/). Но при любых рассылках с хостинга нужно учитывать лимиты последнего на отправку почты.